# Good practice for making service calls

Tags: c#, service, error-handling, try-catch

I'm working on a project that relies extensively on Exchange Web Services. As of now I'm wrapping all of my service calls on `try`/`catch`. While this isn't a problem per say it does clutter code quite a bit by having one line turn into 10~.

Here are the options I see:

1. Create a function such as `bool TryExecute(Action action, Action failCallback)`
2. Interface all of my service calls and use an interceptor to wrap my calls

Are these any alternatives that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that depends on your implementation. I would place the try/catch as near to the point where failure is expected (and can be gracefully handeled) as possible.
For example wrapping those calls into a interface (for testing) and using only a common exception-type otherwise (for example handle EndpointNotFound and wrap any unexpected failure into a ExchangeCommunication-Exception you created yourself).

Both of your options seems to handle every kind of error, and I would not advise this but aside from that it's surely better than going against DRY